# MYSQL Insert Unique Row

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with the following columns

```
IDNumber  //auto incremented ID
ItemCategory  //unique entry
description    //typically blank, not unique
```

I want my categories listed in this table to be unique, but the description isn't always unique.

I've experimented with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as well as MYSQL's `unique` features, but I can only get it to work if my description is also unique.

Any ideas on what I can do instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you have tried so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the description to be unique, then add a unique constraint/index on that column:

```
create index unq_table_description on table(description);
```

The database will then enforce uniqueness on that column, preventing inserts and updates that violate the constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible as this is part of a larger open-source project, and the table is already in use...  We'll see if I can get the project guys to agree to a rewrite, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @AlexSmart . . . Adding an index isn't exactly a rewrite, especially if you are trying to enforce a uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new table with an autoincrement key column, a column with the "unique" key and the description. In this table the "ItemCategory" can be saved a lot of times, based on the times you have an entry for "description". Then use the JOIN function for the "ItemCategory" column on both tables and you can retrieve all the descriptions for the each "unique" item.